# Convert Keras predict output with MultiLabelBinarizer

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I have a Keras ML algorithm with categorical data as the ouput. I used a MultiLabelBinarizer to preprocess my training set and my test set.

Now, I'd like to use that binarizer to retrieve the original labels. But the inverse_transform of the MultiLabelBinarizer expects an array of 0 and 1. The return type of keras Sequential.predict is an array of floats :

```
[1.12341913e-05 1.41614655e-05 2.17968118e-05 3.00095453e-05
 3.14625395e-05 7.41569820e-05 8.29565761e-05 9.98367250e-05
 1.00901299e-04 1.02536709e-04 1.33234425e-04 1.34716029e-04
 1.65971476e-04 1.93201427e-04 2.67350493e-04 3.41955834e-04
 6.69036701e-04 9.62036604e-04 2.26790877e-03 3.79886804e-03
 5.10875024e-02 2.81521738e-01 6.57887399e-01]
```

Ideally I'd like to have a map of label/probas.

Is there a simple way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, simpliest way I found :

```
for i in range(0, len(result[0])):
    print (binarizer.classes_[i], ":", result[0][i])
```